# Service are not launching (micro services) depending of the intellij version

Tags: web-services, kotlin, intellij-idea, jvm, microservices

I have a really weird problem with intellij version.
I have exactly the same project between 2 differents version of intellij and it is working for one(2019.3.5) but not for the last one(2020.3.1) Community edition.

Here is the code which launch all my services :

```
val availableServices = ServiceLoader.load(SomeService::class.java).map { it.name to it }.toMap()
val servicesWithConfiguration = config.services.flatMap { (serviceName, serviceDeployement) ->
    when (val serviceInstance = availableServices[serviceName]) {
        null -> {
            LOGGER.warn("No service registered for name '$serviceName', skipping, it will not be started")
            emptyList()
        }
        else -> listOf(serviceInstance to serviceDeployement)
    }
}
```

Here is my VM options :

```
--add-modules java.se --add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.management/management=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.management/com.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Thanks a lot for the help.

Regards

Comment: Are you using the same version of Java for both of them?

Comment: Yes java 11.0.9

Comment: Might be worth doing some debugging to find out where the issues are concerned. For example, is the list of available services empty? You might have to look at the bytecode generated as it could be different versions of Kirin compiling differently.

Comment: I the bytecode? How I can do that?
I cannot do that cause of the privacy of code.

 

But when I put intellij instead of gradle in the settings it works :

Build,Execution,Deployment>Gradle>Build and run using

Here is a link to my post in IDEA Forum : https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010279859-Service-are-not-launching-micro-services-depending-of-the-intellij-version?page=1#community_comment_360002675339

Comment: You can look at the generated bytecode with `javap` followed by the class name. If you're interested at bytecode, I gave a presentation on it recently -- have a look at my speakerdeck profile if you're interested.

Comment: This one : https://speakerdeck.com/alblue/bite-sized-bytecode-and-classloaders?slide=5 ??

Comment: Yeah, that's the one. It was recorded for the London Java Community and is on YouTube; I've added that into the comments of the video. Hope you find it interesting!